# Accessing id of MPI_Datatype

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I am trying to use PMPI wrapper to record some function parameters, e.g. MPI_Send's parameter. I need to record them and then I could use them to reconstruct content of all those parameters.

The wrapper for MPI_Send looks like this:

```
/* ================== C Wrappers for MPI_Send ================== */
_EXTERN_C_ int PMPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm);
_EXTERN_C_ int MPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm) { 
    int _wrap_py_return_val = 0;

    do_wrap_send_series((char *)"MPI_Send", buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm);
    _wrap_py_return_val = PMPI_Send(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm);
    return _wrap_py_return_val;
}
```

The problem is that I couldn't record pointer's value and use it later on. Pointer could differ across runs.

At least `MPI_Datatype` is pointer type, correct me if I am wrong.

How do I find out MPI_Datatype is pointer type: Compile [this](https://pastebin.com/pmSgybSQ), `mpicc` warns (on x86_64):

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct ompi_datatype_t *’
```

The definition of struct ompi_datatype_t is:

```
struct ompi_datatype_t {
    opal_datatype_t    super;                    /**< Base opal_datatype_t superclass */
    /* --- cacheline 5 boundary (320 bytes) was 32 bytes ago --- */

    int32_t            id;                       /**< OMPI-layers unique id of the type */
    int32_t            d_f_to_c_index;           /**< Fortran index for this datatype */
    struct opal_hash_table_t *d_keyhash;         /**< Attribute fields */

    void*              args;                     /**< Data description for the user */
    void*              packed_description;       /**< Packed description of the datatype */
    uint64_t           pml_data;                 /**< PML-specific information */
    /* --- cacheline 6 boundary (384 bytes) --- */
    char               name[MPI_MAX_OBJECT_NAME];/**< Externally visible name */
    /* --- cacheline 7 boundary (448 bytes) --- */

    /* size: 448, cachelines: 7, members: 7 */
};

typedef struct ompi_datatype_t ompi_datatype_t;
```

So it looks like each MPI_Datatype has a unique id.

So I tried to access the `id` filed with [here](https://pastebin.com/hg9MT7Qf). I got error:

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct ompi_datatype_t’
```

`ompi` should be internal data structure. Is there any way to achive my goal?

Tool to generate PMPI wrapper: [here](https://github.com/LLNL/wrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, `MPI_Datatype` is an opaque handler, so you cannot make any assumption, especially if your wrappers should be portable.

`MPI_Datatype` is indeed a pointer in Open MPI, but it is a number in MPICH iirc.

(older) Fortran uses integer in order to refer a datatype, so one option is to use the following subroutines

- `MPI_Fint MPI_Type_c2f(MPI_Datatype datatype);`
- `MPI_Datatype MPI_Type_f2c(MPI_Fint datatype);`

in order to convert between a `MPI_Datatype` and a `MPI_Fint` (an `int` unless you built Open MPI with 8 bytes Fortran integers)

That being said, if you want to compare datatypes between runs, you might want to consider these subroutines

- `int MPI_Type_set_name(MPI_Datatype type, const char *type_name);`
- `int MPI_Type_get_name(MPI_Datatype type, char *type_name, int *resultlen);`

So you do not have to worry about race conditions nor changing the sequence in which derived datatypes are created by your app.